# Java getting ObjectInputStream ObjectOutputStream from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have an application that is based on server- multiple clients interaction.This is the thread that i use in the server class to create a new thread where i accept all the new sockets:

```
    Thread acceptingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                    listaSocket.add(s);
                    listaOis.add(new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
                    listaOos.add(new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
                    System.out.println("Client connected");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }

    });
    acceptingThread.start();




private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private ArrayList<Socket> listaSocket;
private ArrayList<ObjectInputStream> listaOis;
private ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> listaOos;
```

The lines that block the programs are :

```
                    listaOis.add(new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
                    listaOos.add(new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of the constructor of ObjectInputStream.

Comment: I think serverSocket.accept() is blocking program, it wait for new request to come.

Comment: In my client i'm making a socket that connects to this server.In s i get the socket from the client.ObjectInputStream takes an InputStream in his constructor.I get that from s.getInputStream()

Answer (score 3):

Your code is blocking in this particular line:

```
                    listaOis.add(new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
```

Take note of the behavior of this `ObjectInputStream` constructor. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)):

> Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. **This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header.**

Getting the `InputStream` from the incoming connection means that serialized data needs to be sent through the connection. This means that you have to do the following before the constructor will proceed:

1. Connect from the client side. I presume you are already doing this since you can get through `socket.accept()`
2. Open an `OutputStream` using the new connection.
3. Wrap the `OutputStream` with an `ObjectOutputStream`.
4. Send some data through the `ObjectOutputStream` (i.e. write some serializable data into it and flush).